# Constraint in a many to many relation

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I'm trying to solve a problem. I have a table POLYGON and a table VERTEX; every polygon can be associated to a minimum of 3 or more vertices, every vertices can be associated to 1 or more polygons.
Since it is a many to many relation I created another table that contain polygon's primary key and vertex primary key.
Now how can I add the constraint that the polygon must have 3 or more vertices?

ATTENTION: It is not 0..3 multiplicity but 3..*. I didn't find any question with the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you need to use a trigger for this.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to set it because if i check before inserting if there are 3 or less vertices then i can't make the insertion possible.

Comment: @apc This question is re a minimum of 3, requiring a different answer than for a maximum of 3. The alleged duplicate isn't clear so should not be used as a duplicate. Moreover it is re either exactly or maximum 3 and only if it is ever clarified to exactly 3 could it be a duplicate. Moreover the the asker says "restrict to 0,3" in the comments, so if it's ever edited to be clear it will not be a duplicate.

Comment: I still believe this question is a duplicate of [this other StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280427/146325). However, some people including the OP have objected that is is not an exact duplicate so I have reopened it, and also answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three tables, POLYGON, VERTEX and POLYGON_VERTICES. POLYGON_VERTICES is an intersection table allowing a many-to-many relationship between POLYGON and VERTEX.

```
create table polygon
    (polygon_id number generated always as identity
     , type varchar2(30) not null unique
     , constraint polygon_pk  primary key (polygon_id) )
/
create table vertex
    (vertex_id number generated always as identity
     , side varchar2(10) not null unique
     , constraint vertex_pk  primary key (vertex_id) )
/
create table polygon_vertices
    (polygon_id number not null
     , vertex_id number not null
     , constraint polygon_vertices_uk unique (polygon_id, vertex_id)
     , constraint polygon_vertices_polygon_fk foreign key (polygon_id) references polygon (polygon_id)
     , constraint polygon_vertices_vertex_fk foreign key (vertex_id) references vertex(vertex_id)
     )
/
```

We need to enforce a business rule, *A Polygon Must Have At Least Three Sides*. To do this we must count the number of VERTEX_ID for a given POLYGON_ID, which means the rule spans multiple records.  The term for this is Assertion, which is [part of the SQL standard but not (yet) implemented in Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028). So there is no easy way of enforcing the role declaratively;   we can't put an aggregation in a CHECK constraint on POLYGON_VERTICES.

There are various workarounds. We could build a FOR EACH ROW trigger to maintain a list of the new POLYGON_IDs in session memory and an AFTER STATEMENT trigger to do the count and enforce the rule. That is clunky. We could use a stored procedure to manage the inserts. That doesn't help if users can find a way to insert directly into POLYGON_VERTICES.

But there is an approach which is both safe and transparent: we build an aggregating materialized view over POLYGON_VERTICES and put the check constraint on that:

```
create materialized view pv_sides
refresh on commit 
as 
select polygon_id 
        , count(*) as no_of_sides
from polygon_vertices
group by polygon_id
/

alter table pv_sides
   add constraint valid_polygon_ck check 
       ( no_of_sides >= 3 )
/

create materialized view log on polygon_vertices
/
```

[Here is a LiveSQL Demo of the full script (free OTN login required).](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f71jswic6qur5ykhdh6y6c6yx)