# Error in calling user defined function while adding check constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle, check-constraint

I want to add a check constraint that will make sure no one can enter more than one spouse in family table. I am trying to use a custom defined function for the same. I am doing some thing like this:

```
ALTER TABLE PMT_TRN_FAMILY
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SPOUSE
CHECK (GETSPOUSE(M_CODE) = 'True');
```

Definition of Function GETSPOUSE is here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETSPOUSE (
    P_M_CODE IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR
IS Output VARCHAR2(5);
S_CNT NUMBER(2,0);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO S_CNT FROM PMT_TRN_FAMILY WHERE M_CODE = P_M_CODE AND RELATIONS='Spouse';
    IF S_CNT > 0 THEN
        return ('False');
    END IF;
    return ('True');
END;
```

Here *M_code* is the code of a candidate and *Relations* is column which stores type of relations.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205) I got to know that we cannot use user defined functions in check constraint, so is there any other way I can accomplish this in oracle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually I was on the verge of deleting that comment because I've expanded it into an actual answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use functions in check constraints, due to the internal architecture of the Oracle database: compiling a function and validating a constraint are separate concerns.

Maybe what you're looking for is a SQL assertion. Oracle doesn't support these (yet) but please read [this answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280427/146325) which explains how you could implement a workaround using a materialized view.

However, it may be that all you need is a function-based index. I'm assuming that PMT_TRN_FAMILY implements some form of directed graph. So that `M_CODE -> RELATIONS -> N_CODE` can be used to represent `MIKKI is SPOUSE of NIKKI` or `MO is FATHER of NOAH`. You can enforce monogamy  between spouses while still allowing people to have more than one kid like this:

```
create UNIQUE index only_one_spouse_fbi on  PMT_TRN_FAMILY
        (M_CODE
         , case when RELATIONS='Spouse' then M_CODE else N_CODE end)
/
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f66c8/2).

---

If this doesn't solve your issue then please [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49789358/edit) to include more details, such as table structures and some sample data.

Comment: For your test data, if you do `insert into PMT_TRN_FAMILY values (1, 'Sibling', 7);` then you violate the unique index as there is a duplicate `M_CODE`, `N_CODE` pair even though neither is a `SPOUSE`.

Comment: @mt0 - and that would be wrong because it is valid to be somebody's father and somebody's brother simultaneously? Hmmm, maybe in the mountains of Appalachia or the flats of Norfolk. ;-) But you're right, I made an assumption about the business rules which isn't in the text of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing at your table structure:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e686/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE(
  M_CODE NUMBER(20,0) CONSTRAINT PEOPLE__M_CODE__PK PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE PMT_TRN_FAMILY (
  M_CODE     NUMBER(20,0) CONSTRAINT FAMILY__M_CODE__FK
                            REFERENCES PEOPLE ( M_CODE ),
  RELATIONS  VARCHAR2(20),
  RELATED_TO NUMBER(20,0) CONSTRAINT FAMILY__RELATED_TO__FK
                            REFERENCES PEOPLE ( M_CODE )
);
```

Then we can modify it adding a unique index checking that for each `RELATIONS='SPOUSE'` there is only one `M_CODE`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FAMILY__ONE_SPOUSE__U ON PMT_TRN_FAMILY (
  CASE RELATIONS WHEN 'SPOUSE' THEN M_CODE END
);
```

Inserting some test data:

```
INSERT INTO PEOPLE ( M_CODE )
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;

INSERT INTO PMT_TRN_FAMILY ( M_CODE, RELATIONS, RELATED_TO )
  SELECT 1, 'SPOUSE', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'PARENT', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'PARENT', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'SIBLING', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'CHILD',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'CHILD',  6 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM PMT_TRN_FAMILY
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e686/1/0)**:

```
| M_CODE | RELATIONS | RELATED_TO |
|--------|-----------|------------|
|      1 |    SPOUSE |          2 |
|      1 |    PARENT |          3 |
|      1 |    PARENT |          4 |
|      1 |   SIBLING |          4 |
|      1 |     CHILD |          5 |
|      1 |     CHILD |          6 |
```

Then there are multiple parents/children (and even someone who has multiple non-spouse relationships) but only one spouse.

**Query 2**:

```
INSERT INTO PMT_TRN_FAMILY ( M_CODE, RELATIONS, RELATED_TO )
  VALUES ( 1, 'SPOUSE', 7 )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e686/1/1)**:

Trying to add a second spouse then you get an error of "one spouse violated":

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (USER_4_2700A6.FAMILY__ONE_SPOUSE__U) violated
```